# Bunched up x axis ticks on multi panelled plot in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am attempting to make a multi-panelled plot from three individual plots (see images).However, I am unable to rectify the bunched x-axis tick labels when the plots are in the multi-panel format. Following is the script for the individual plots and the multi-panel:

Individual Plot:

```
NewDat [[60]]
EstRes <- NewDat [[60]]

EstResPlt = ggplot(EstRes,aes(Distance3, `newBa`))+geom_line() + scale_x_continuous(n.breaks = 10, limits = c(0, 3500))+ scale_y_continuous(n.breaks = 10, limits = c(0,25))+ xlab("Distance from Core (μm)") + ylab("Ba:Ca concentration(μmol:mol)") + geom_hline(yintercept=2.25, linetype="dashed", color = "red")+ geom_vline(xintercept = 1193.9, linetype="dashed", color = "grey")+ geom_vline(xintercept = 1965.5, linetype="dashed", color = "grey") + geom_vline(xintercept = 2616.9, linetype="dashed", color = "grey") + geom_vline(xintercept = 3202.8, linetype="dashed", color = "grey")+ geom_vline(xintercept = 3698.9, linetype="dashed", color = "grey") 
 
EstResPlt
```

Multi-panel plot:

```
MultiP <- grid.arrange(MigrPlt,OcResPlt,EstResPlt, nrow =1)
```

I have attempted to include:

```
MultiP <- grid.arrange(MigrPlt,OcResPlt,EstResPlt, nrow =1)+ 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text (angle = 45)) )
MultiP
```

but have only received errors. It's not necessary for all tick marks to be included. An initial, mid and end value is sufficient and therefore they would not need to all be included or angled. I'm just not sure how to do this. Assistance would be much appreciated.

[image: Multi-panelled plot]
[image: Individual Panel]

Comment: If that code is exactly you used, there is `)` at the end that's unnecessary typo. Moreover, you may rotate each point manually, before using `grid.arrange`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The extra ) was a typo and had no effect once removed. What script would you use to rotate each point manually? I tried this to no avail:                                                                                                                    
```
MultiP <- theme(axis.text.x = element_text (angle = 45))+ grid.arrange(MigrPlt,OcResPlt,EstResPlt, nrow =1)
MultiP

```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options to resolve the crowded axes. Let's consider the following example which parallels your case. The default labelling strategy wouldn't overcrowd the x-axis.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(patchwork)
library(scales)

df <- data.frame(
  x = seq(0, 3200, by = 20),
  y = cumsum(rnorm(161))
)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_line()

(p + p + p) / p &
  scale_x_continuous(
    name = "Distance (um)"
  )
```

[image]

However, because you've given `n.breaks = 10` to the scale, it becomes crowded. So a simple solution would just be to remove that.

```r
(p + p + p) / p &
  scale_x_continuous(
    n.breaks = 10, 
    name = "Distance (um)"
  )
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could convert the micrometers to millimeters, which makes the labels less wide.

```r
(p + p + p) / p &
  scale_x_continuous(
    n.breaks = 10,
    labels = label_number(scale = 1e-3, accuracy = 0.1),
    name = "Distance (mm)"
  )
```

[image]

Yet another alternative is to put breaks only every `n` units, in the case below, a 1000. This happens to coincide with omitting `n.breaks = 10` by chance.

```r
(p + p + p) / p &
  scale_x_continuous(
    breaks = breaks_width(1000), 
    name = "Distance (um)"
  )
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Brilliance! Thank you Teunbrand (https://stackoverflow.com/users/11374827/teunbrand)

Answer (score 0):

I thought it would be better to show with an example.

What I mean was, you made `MigrPlt`, `OcResPlt`, `EstResPlt` each with `ggplot() +.....`. For plot that you want to rotate x axis, add `+  theme(axis.text.x = element_text (angle = 45))`.

For example, in `iris` data, only rotate x axis text for `a` like

```
a <- ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Width, Sepal.Length)) +
  geom_point() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text (angle = 45))
b <- ggplot(iris, aes(Petal.Width, Petal.Length)) +
  geom_point() 

gridExtra::grid.arrange(a,b, nrow = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Park (https://stackoverflow.com/users/16729175/park), that answered my question. Out of interest, rather than angling the tick labels, how would I go about removing every second tick label? So for example, on the x axis in the plot on the right above (Petal.Width), how would I exclude to only have 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 instead of 0.0, 0.5, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5?